# How to add dependency property to FrameworkElement driven classes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I need key and Value property in all controls which are drives from FrameworkElement class in wpf. key and value property are needed for some internal purpose. I know we have a Tag property which is used for saving custom data. I need two more such properties.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another property, as you know `Tag` property will allow you to save custom data.
This is example of how you can store data in the `Tag`.

```
public class Customdata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

private void setDataInTag(FrameworkElement obj, Customdata objCustomData)
{
    obj.Tag = objCustomData;
}

private Customdata GetValueFromElement(FrameworkElement obj)
{
    Customdata objCustomData = new Customdata();

    if (obj.Tag!=null && obj.Tag.GetType() == typeof(Customdata))
    {
        objCustomData = (Customdata)obj.Tag;

        return objCustomData;
    }
}
```

I think it is simple now :)

Comment: Tag property is already used to store another piece of data. Don't want to have token separated value as it will cost at receiving end while splitting the token separated value.

Answer (score -1):

You should create your own [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943(v=vs.95).aspx). 
Just create new class, write `propa` codesnippet, press tab, tab :)

in xaml you can then set and get the property on any dependency object, just like you can use Grid.Column or Canvas.Left on any element.